# Android: Start & close application at user specified times

Tags: android

How can I start my application on a time specified by the user.
Lets say start time is 8:00 am and end time is 4:00p.m
I am storing the value of start time and end time in shared preference.

```
public static synchronized void scheduleTimeoutCheck(final int time) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time / 100);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time % 100);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1); // Add 1 second of additional delay
    if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() <= 0) {
        // Time has already past, schedule for next day
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

    new Timer(true).schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // "its time for scheduleTimeoutCheck
            /*if (Utility.checkSystemTimeout())
            {*/
                // Re - schedule this for the next day //
                Utility.checkLockdownAppSchedule();
           // }
        }
    }, calendar.getTime());

    System.out.println("Timeout Check is scheduled to run at " + calendar.getTime().toString());
}
```

Comment: stick to strider's asnwer but please make it beter using latest JobScheduler api in place of AlarmManager. You can refer it from http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Comment: @Hardeep Good point!, But remember that `JobScheduler` is **API 21** and up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What u wanna do is fully described [here](http://www.accella.net/knowledgebase/scheduling-code-execution-on-android/)

First schedule your times somewhere, like in your `onCreate()`:

```
//create new calendar instance for your start time
Calendar startTime= Calendar.getInstance();

//set the time to 4AM or your USER SPECIFIED start time
startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) LayoutActivity.this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

//create a pending intent to be called at 4AM
PendingIntent startPI = PendingIntent.getService(yourActivity.this, 0, new Intent("startApplicationReceiver"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//schedule time for pending intent, and set the interval to day so that this event will repeat at the selected time every day
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, startPI);

//----------------------------------------------------

//create new calendar instance for your end time
Calendar endCalender = Calendar.getInstance();

//Set the time to 8PM or your USER SPECIFIED end time
endCalender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
endCalender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
endCalender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

//create a pending intent to be called at 8 AM
PendingIntent endPI= PendingIntent.getService(yourActivity.this, 0, new Intent("endApplicationReceiver"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

//schedule time for pending intent, and set the interval to day so that this event will repeat at the selected time every day
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, endCalender.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, endPI);
```

Add your Alarm classes:

**Start time receiver:**

```
public class startApplicationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {                                 //Start your application
            Intent intent = new Intent();    
             intent.setClassName("package.name", "<your_package_name>");
            startActivity(intent);
         } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {  //You don't have the application installed
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
         }

        //!!!If you WANT to repeat the start application alarm EVERY day
        //Comment/Remove the next 4 lines

        //Cancel start time alarm
        Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivity.this, startApplicationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent startPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(startPI);
    }
}
```

**End time receiver**

```
public class endApplicationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //finish your application
        finish();

        //!!!If you WANT to repeat the endapplication alarm EVERY day
        //Comment/Remove the next 4 lines

        //Cancel end time alarm
        Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivity.this, endApplicationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent endPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(endPI);
    }
}
```

And the last thing u need to do is register your receivers in your

**Manifest.XML:**

```
<receiver android:name="startAlarm" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="startApplicationReceiver" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name="endAlarm" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="endApplicationReceiver" >
            </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This should help u out.

**Note:** you must have started your application manually at least once, to register the alarm receivers.

Comment: To make this process much better and efficient.Please use the latest JobScheduler api.

Comment: Thnx, This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Start application it means you want to start activity at exact time? 
It is not good user case i think. But for this task you have to use `AlarmManager, plus a Service` with your logic (Service will not visible for user). 
If you want notify user about something you can use NotificationManager. Or in last case you can start semitransparent activity with dialog. Remember that for starting activity from service you should set`key` `SINGLE_TASK`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **AlarmManager** for achieving such functionality.

To take a good grasp on how to implement it, [you can study this good article.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html) and [this one by Java Code Geeks.](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-alarmmanager-tutorial.html)